# Resources inside scope have wrong update path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have the following routes:

```
namespace :admin do
  scope 'users/:user_id' do
    resources :orders
  end
end
```

In my controller I have the following:

```
before_action :find_user
before_action :find_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
...

def new
  @order = @user.orders.new
end

def edit

end

def create
  @order = @user.orders.new(order_params)
  ...
end

def update
  if @order.update(order_params)
  ...
end

...

def find_user
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end

def find_order
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end
```

My `form_with` is looking like this:

```
= form_with model: [:admin, @order], local: true do |f|
  etc
```

The new and create paths are working correctly, and generating the good path: /admin/user/(user_id)/orders

However, the update_path isn't working correctly, and generates the following path:

/admin/user/(order_id)/orders/(order_id).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide the output of `rails routes` command

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your `@user` to a model parameter:

```
= form_with model: [:admin, @user, @order], local: true do |f|
```

Too instead of `scope` you can use nested resources:

```
namespace :admin do
 resources :users do
   resources :orders
 end
end
```